# Is there a way to selectively load external scripts through URL parameters in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently working on a website that has a very specific requirement: **the possibility to test the page performance without any external scripts.** All of this company's sites need a considerable amount of scripts to be injected, as they are the company's proprietary cookie notice and analytics scripts. But since they are so many, they compromise the speed tests a lot, so there should be a way to deactivate them to know the actual performance of the site.

In previous projects, made with **Gatsby.js**, parameters could be passed to the URL, and depending on the parameter, a certain script would not load, or even none of them would. For example: Passing `?analytics=false` makes the analytics scripts not load, `?cookie=false` makes the cookie notice not load, or `?scripts=false` stops all of them from loading. This way, one can simply go to Google's PageSpeed Insights and type the URL with these parameters to test the performance.

The project I'm working on, however, is a **Next.js** site. To load the scripts, I put them in a component called `HeadScripts.tsx` and load the component inside the `next/head` component, like so:

```js
const App = () => {
  return <>
    <Head>
      ... any meta tag
      <HeadScripts/>
    </Head>
    ...The page component itself
  </>
}
```

This loads them with no problem. To make them conditional to the URL params, though, my first instinct was to get the params from `next/router` and based on them, I check if I should load all scripts or not, like so:

```js
const App = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [shouldScriptsLoad, setShouldScriptsLoad] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    //Example logic that checks if the url has a '?noscripts' param
    !router.query.noscripts && setShouldScriptsLoad(true); 
  },[router.isReady])
  return <>
    <Head>
      ... any meta tag
      {shouldScriptsLoad ? <HeadScripts/> : null}
    </Head>
    ...The page component itself
  </>
}
```

Here, I'm initializing a state as `false`. But, if the state changes to `true` during the check, the scripts don't load accordingly. If I initialize it as `true` then, the script will load before the check, and it will be irrelevant.

Upon checking the Gatsby site and how they do it, there is a difference that might be key to the problem: they don't have the script addition logic in a React component like Helmet. They do it in the `gatsby-ssr.js` file, by encapsulating each script on another script with a `load` listener and pushing it to `<head>`, to check the parameters before each one can load. Here's an example:

```js
headComponents.push(
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      async={true}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                let hostURL = new URL(window.location.href);
                let isDisabled = hostURL.searchParams.get('the parameter to be checked');
                if(!isDisabled) {   
                  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                  var script = document.createElement('script');
                  script.type = 'text/javascript';
                  script.async = 'true';
                  script.src = 'the script URL';                  
                  setTimeout(() => head.appendChild(script), 'append the script after some time'});}
              });
            `,
      }}
      id="the-script-id"
    />
);

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents(headComponents);
};
```

Probably this method was used because the sites are hosted on Netlify, so they could take advantage of SSR, but my site can't. Due to an infrastructure limitation, we have to build the site manually and send it to a server over FTP, so I can't use Next's `getServerSideProps` to figure something out from there.

So, after this long post, my question is: **is there actually a way to do such thing on a Next.js site?** Perhaps a way to put logic before the scripts are loaded?

Thank you all for your time, in advance. I would appreciate any help at all!

Comment: Can you show us the actual logic you have inside the `useEffect` that sets the state?

Comment: @juliomalves Sorry for the delay, I added the logic there. As I said in the post, if I initialize the state as true, it won't prevent the load if it turns into false. If initialized as false, the scripts will never load. Either way can sometimes cause a page refresh, but I couldn't simulate this behaviour properly.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour you describe - when I change the state from `false` to `true` the script loads properly. What's inside `HeadScripts`? Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I have exactly same situation. I am using `nextjs`. I tried `react-helmet` and tried using `useEffect` like the example you have given @LeonardoOliveira. I still have not been able to figure it out. Could you let me know if you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry for such an astronomical delay. I declared this to my team as an infrastructure limitation, and left the company a couple months after, so I don't have any insight on a potential solution they possibly came up with. Sorry @SureshKUMARMukhiya! I am closing the question :(